# HTML concatenation issues in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a dynamic HTML which I'll append using jquery before append if I'll console the HTML everything looks fine but after append in browser  The whole structure messed up.

Here is my HTML :

```
<script>
var title = "my title";

var toolbar ='<hm_toolbar user="current_user " upp="hm"  index="hmIndex "></hm><synapse_toolbar uuid=" hm.hm_pk " my-method="get_linked_facts" ng-if=" flag == true "></synapse_toolbar>';

var map_html = '<a onclick="panToMarker(' + lat + ',' + long + ')"> ' + title +'"</a>' + toolbar ;

var li_html = "$('#" + title + "').append('<li class=\"list-group-item\"><div dynamic=\" " + map_html + " \"></div></li> ')" ;

var g =title.replace(/ /g,"_");;

var fn = "function "+ g +"(){ console.log('--working--'); "+ li_html +"; }";
    console.log(fn)
   eval(fn);
  }
  </script>
```

When the above li_HTML does its work means append the HTML the appended is all messed up

Appended HTML :

```
<li class="list-group-item"><div pantomarker(49.711083,6.251445)"="" dynamic=" &lt;a onclick="> Test"<hm_toolbar index="hmIndex " upp="hm" user="current_user "></hm_toolbar><synapse_toolbar ng-if=" flag == true " my-method="get_linked_facts" uuid=" hm.hm_pk "></synapse_toolbar> "&gt;</div></li>
```

I know I have messed up the concatenation using with quotes but I am not able to fixed the bug .

Comment: try escaping your `'` characters inside the string. do it like: `var li_html = "$(\'#" + title + "\').append(\'<li class=\"list-group-item\"><div dynamic=\"" + map_html + " \"></div></li> \')" ;
`

Comment: @Vance nop , no luck

Comment: @saf there is the " quote is mising at var map_html = '<a onclick="panToMarker(' + lat + ',' + long + ')"> ' + title +'"</a>' + toolbar ; i think that is making problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the `console.log()` looks OK but you have `eval()` after that which means that you have to escape some quotes twice.

Try this:

```
var toolbar ='<hm_toolbar user=\\\'current_user \\\' upp=\\\'hm\\\'  index=\\\'hmIndex \\\'></hm><synapse_toolbar uuid=\\\' hm.hm_pk \\\' my-method=\\\'get_linked_facts\\\' ng-if=\\\' flag == true \\\'></synapse_toolbar>';

var map_html = '<a onclick=\\\'panToMarker(' + lat + ',' + long + ')\\\'> ' + title +'</a>' + toolbar ;
```